# using vbscript to read / save a webpage

Tags: vbscript

goal:
log into the web page
and save the html to a file for parsing later.

the html on the page is just a list of users and when they logged in and off.

When you load the web page up  a javascript box pops up and asks for login information

i can fill this with SendKeys but i really want to do this without a window popping up

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")  

IE.Visible = False ' doesn't set IE page as invisible?????

IE.Navigate "https://mysite/site/console/client-log.jsp"
      'how do i fill in the box ???
```

Comment: I see distinction between the title and actual question, however, if you have not an access to the source of that web page to modify it design, then how you expect to skip that popup dialog?

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest to use something like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to identify the request that does the actual login, and then use that information in an [XMLHttpRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh453379.aspx).

```
url      = "..."
filename = "..."

Set req = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
req.open "POST", url, False
req.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
req.send "field1=foo&field2=bar&..."

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fso.OpenTextFile(filename, 2, True).WriteLine req.responseText
```

If the response is UTF-8 encoded you may need to use an [ADODB.Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677486%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object for saving the content.

```
Set stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
stream.Open
stream.Type     = 2 'text
stream.Position = 0
stream.Charset  = "utf-8"
stream.WriteText req.responseText
stream.SaveToFile filename, 2
stream.Close
```