# array_fill_keys in Visual Basic

Tags: php, arrays, vbscript, vb6

Is there are function equal to php array_fill_keys in visualbasic?

In php i do:

```
<?php 
$array1 = array( 
    "a" => "first", 
    "b" => "second", 
    "c" => "something", 
    "red" 
); 

$array2 = array( 
    "a" => "first", 
    "b" => "something", 
    "letsc" 
); 

print_r(array_fill_keys($array1, $array2)); 
?>
```

How to do this in VB?

Comment: No, because Visual Basic arrays aren't associative hashmaps as they are in PHP. Maybe you want to be using a dictionary?

Comment: Maybe. Problem is how to hold dictionary values in text file?

Comment: Serialize the objects. However, this sounds a bit like a design smell. Could you add more information as to what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to save into text file data from mssql database, it must be one string fieldName->fieldValue for all columns, and then use this text file to read, add or change thoose fields

Comment: Change the fields in the database via the text file? Why not work directly with the db?

Comment: Because this is a sessions text files in ASP-Classic and directly to db is not possible for performance reasons. LOOK HERE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32175762/read-and-write-arrays-to-from-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case you really need an `array_fill_keys`-alike function and can live with a dictionary:

```
Option Explicit

' stolen from http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php:
'  Fill a dictionary with values (xValue), specifying keys (aKeys)
'  Fills a dictionary with the value of the xValue parameter, using the values of aKeys as keys.
Function array_fill_keys(aKeys, xValue)
  Dim t : Set t = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  Dim k
  For Each k In aKeys
      t(k) = xValue
  Next
  Set array_fill_keys = t
End Function

Sub FEDicO(d, o)
  Dim k
  For Each k In d.Keys
      o.apply d, k
  Next
End Sub

Class cPPrintLn
  Sub apply(d, k)
    WScript.Echo "  ", k, "=>", d(k)
  End Sub
End Class

' $keys = array('foo', 5, 10, 'bar');
' $a = array_fill_keys($keys, 'banana');
' print_r($a);
' The above example will output:
' Array(
'   [foo] => banana
'   [5] => banana
'   [10] => banana
'   [bar] => banana
' )

Dim aKeys : aKeys    = Array("foo", 5, 10, "bar")
Dim dicX  : Set dicX = array_fill_keys(aKeys, "Banana")
WScript.Echo "dicX:"
FEDicO dicX, New cPPrintLn
```

output:

```
cscript 32219456.vbs
dicX:
   foo => Banana
   5 => Banana
   10 => Banana
   bar => Banana
```