# Save page as html in VBscript

Tags: html, vbscript, asp-classic

I have a VBScript/classic ASP page creating another page containing a generated HTML table. This page I want to also automatically to be printed and saved at a specific location as an htm/html file.

Due to customer demands, this has to be done in VBScript/classic ASP.

The closest I have come to this is:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/292485
which is a link that isn't working.......

And...

```
<% 

Dim hElm As IHTMLElement
Dim htmltext As String
Dim fso As Object
Dim file As Object

Set hElm = WebBrowser1.Document.all.tags("html").Item(0)
htmltext = hElm.outerHTML

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set file = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Logs\test.html",2,True)

file.write htmltext
file.close

Set file = nothing
Set fso = nothing

%>
```

Which generates a failure and no test.html file...
If i manually creates a test.html file it will delete the file - which is not intended.

If i use the original code `Dim hElm As IHTMLElement` etc and not only `Dim hElm` it comes with a **Error 500**.

This might be a minor thing but I'm really blank on this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which line is throwing error and what error exactly?

Comment: Does "C:\Logs\test.html" exist? if not, use fso.CreateTextFile() instead

Comment: you may also want to using adodb.stream - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914099/using-vbscript-to-read-save-a-webpage

Comment: Is the error to do with WebBrowser1 not found. That code looks from ASP.Net

Comment: @JoshMontgomery Thank you. I have updated code. I haven't worked with ASP.NET before....

I'm unsure why this doesn't work. The script need to be in classic ASP due to limitations

Comment: So are you all set then, or do you need further assistance?

Comment: @JoshMontgomery I could need some more assistance as it still doesn't create a file. I have created a file manually and the script deleted it! I believe the "WebBrowser1" have something to do with it...

I need the output as htm/html.

Comment: the code you posted looks to be either visual basic code or vb.net code, and is def not ASP/vbscript code, as there are no data types specified in ASP. Please verify what language you're using. Also, make sure whatever folder you're writing too has full permissions to do so.finally, please make sure your original code is the most up to date.

Comment: this looks like VB code to me not ASP. `WebBrowser1` may be a custom assembly